# How can I send ajax over mobile phones?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mobile

I am trying to send an image of a qrcode via ajax to a php script that it can be decoded. After that it is send back to the client, so that JQuery can fire the form with the code.
On my desktop PC this code is working fine.

On my iPhone it doesnt work.

**JQuery:**

```
$('#file').on('change', function (ev) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "asyn/decodeQr.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData($("#myform")[0]),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function (data) {
            if(data != "false")
            {
                $('#shopToken').val(data);
                $("#myform").submit();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#shopToken').val("nop");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <form method="post" action="?page=connect_shop&save=1&token={$SESSION.link_validation}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{trans var=sys_shop_connect_shop_label}</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input type="text" id="shopToken" name="shopToken"  value="{if isset($POST.shopToken)}{$POST.shopToken}{/if}" class="form-control" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="{trans var="sys_shop_connect_shop_jqfv_error"}">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{trans var=sys_shop_connect_shop_label_qrcode}</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input id="file" name="file" type="file" accept="image/*" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-success">{trans var="sys_global_button_save"}</button></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried it with a button and a click event, that didnt help.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't matter if you're sending the data from a mobile device or a desktop computer, it's the browser that runs the code and nowadays they interpret it pretty much the same way. You're problem might be coming from elsewhere. I would suggest plugging in your mobile device and opening the inspector to see what data is passed and received. I suggest you google "How to debug website on mobile device" since it depends on your device's OS.

Comment: @VVV okay, I have tested the chrome://inspect and tested it. No results. So I tested if it would work with a console.log(), that worked. So it is no JQuery problem I think.

Comment: You need to go to the "network" tab in order to see Ajax requests.

Comment: @VVV I think I found the problem. On my iPhone I did send a picture taken by the camera, so not as good as a snapshot from a windows screen. The qr code decoder 
 khanamiryan/qrcode-detector-decoder ran into this error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted. So 4GB of RAM set it to work, but without a result. So now I have to think about a different solution, to decode a qrcode taken by a mobile device.